# Windows Authentication Active Directory login dialog on Dotnet Core 2

Tags: c#, active-directory, .net-core

I am developing an in-house web site that needs to use Active Directory to allow users to log in.  We are developing in Dotnet core V2, using Linux/Docker as the target o/s.

The client wants the 'standard' Windows authentication dialog box to appear on the web site to allow users to log in, rather than provid a web page.

I have found some code that will allow us to verify the credentials, but I somehow need to get those from Windows.

How do I make the generic login dialog appear?

Comment: If your client won't mind entering username and password, then you could use [my sample project at GitHub](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetCoreActiveDirectoryStarterKit#user-login) which should work in Linux.

Comment: HTTP Basic authentication will make the browser ask for the password (should use https though), maybe thats enough for your client. Not sure if you can use the Kerberos in your environment. One alternative is to use [ADFS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx) which is basically SSO for MS Active Directory.

Comment: @Win I have already seen your code, and incorporated many of the things into my project (with full attribution, of course), so thank you for that, but the customer doesn't want a custom form.  They are used to seeing the standard Windows dialog as on their existing system.   I think I have found a way to do what is required, but haven't got far enough to actually try it out.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this question.

It's just a matter of responding to the HTTP request with a status of 401, and a header which includes:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

There are, of course, lots of other things to do.  In dotnet core 2, I've written an AuthenticationHandler (based on code from @Win), but this was the key to getting the dialog box to be shown.